# How to get the objects inside an array of objects which is inside an document in mongoose/mongodb?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is the structure of the document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5548b2b79b9567341c77d352"),
    "messages" : [
        {
            "subject" : "fresh subject ",
            "from" : ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5548b5dab9279faf1c1b8688"),
            "created" : ISODate("2015-05-05T12:21:46.261Z"),
            "read" : true,
            "message" : "fresh message ",
            "participants" : [
                ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31"), //logged in user
                ObjectId("5530af38576214dd3553331c")
            ]
        },
        {
            "subject" : " subjet",
            "from" : ObjectId("5530af38576214dd3553331c"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5548b608b9279faf1c1b8689"),
            "created" : ISODate("2015-05-05T12:22:32.809Z"),
            "read" : true,
            "message" : "is fresh?",
            "participants" : [
                ObjectId("5530af38576214dd3553331c")
            ]
        }
    ],
    "participants" : [
        ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31"),
        ObjectId("5530af38576214dd3553331c")
    ],
    "__v" : 2
}
```

There are several objects inside the messages array of a perticular object. I want to get the objects inside the messages array only if the participants array of that object contains logged in user.

I have object Id of the document (5548b2b79b9567341c77d352) and I have the logged in user id (5534b2992a104ed914435c31).
How to do the same in mongoose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use MongoDB's **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to get the desired result. The aggregation pipeline would consist of an initial step which has a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator that filters the documents based on the criteria above. The next pipeline stage would be the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator that deconstructs the messages array from the input documents to output a document for each element. A further [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) filter then returns only the documents with the participant id. The final step with the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator then passes along the documents with only the specified fields to the result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5548b2b79b9567341c77d352"),
            "messages.participants": ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31")
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$messages"
    },
    {
        "$match": {            
            "messages.participants": ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31")
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "messages": 1
        }
    }

])
```

**Result**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "messages" : {
                "subject" : "fresh subject ",
                "from" : ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("5548b5dab9279faf1c1b8688"),
                "created" : ISODate("2015-05-05T12:21:46.261Z"),
                "read" : true,
                "message" : "fresh message ",
                "participants" : [ 
                    ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31"), 
                    ObjectId("5530af38576214dd3553331c")
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

In Mongoose you could use the same **[aggregation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)** pipeline as follows:

```
// Using the pipeline builder
Model.aggregate({
        "$match: {
            ""_id" : ObjectId("5548b2b79b9567341c77d352"),
            "messages.participants": ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31")
        }
    })
    .unwind("messages")
    .match({ "messages.participants": ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31") })
    .project({
        "_id": 0,
        "messages": 1
    })
    .exec(function (err, res) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log(res); 
    });

// Or the simple aggregate method
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5548b2b79b9567341c77d352"),
            "messages.participants": ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31")
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$messages"
    },
    {
        "$match": {            
            "messages.participants": ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31")
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "messages": 1
        }
    }

]

Model.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, res) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(res); 
});
```

Comment: But I also want to populate 'from' and the 'participants' fields. When I tried with populate, it is showing the following error. Object #<Aggregate> has no method 'populate'

Comment: @SachinKalsi You never mentioned anything about populating the `from` and `participants` field in your question. This solution directly addresses what you asked in the question. You can't use populate with Mongoose aggregate method. In the Aggregation Framework, the returned fields are built by you, and you're able to "rename" document properties and this means Mongoose can't identify that your referenced documents will be available in the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution apart from the aggregation framework is to use the [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator.

For example:

```
var id = '5548b2b79b9567341c77d352';
var loggedInUserId = '5534b2992a104ed914435c31';
var projection = {
    participants: 1,
    messages: {
        $elemMatch: { participants: new ObjectId(loggedInUserId) }
    }
};

Model.findById(id, projection, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

This will output:

```
{ _id: 5548b2b79b9567341c77d352,
  participants: [ 5534b2992a104ed914435c31, 5530af38576214dd3553331c ],
  messages: 
   [ { participants: [Object],
       message: 'fresh message ',
       read: true,
       created: Tue May 05 2015 09:21:46 GMT-0300 (BRT),
       _id: 5548b5dab9279faf1c1b8688,
       from: 5534b2992a104ed914435c31,
       subject: 'fresh subject ' } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the subdocument arrays (splits them into their own documents that you can match against.  The query I would use:

```
.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$messages"},
    {$match:
        {"messages.participants": ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31")}
    }
])
```

This will return a separate `message` document in the result set for each `message` subdocument that matches that participant.

Using Mongoose constructs this would look something like:

```
Conversation
    .aggregate({$unwind: "messages"})
    .match({
        "messages.participants": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31")
    })
    .exec(cb);
```

The first `$match` is not strictly necessary but

Comment: But I also want to populate 'from' and the 'participants' fields. When I tried with populate, it is showing the following error.
Object #<Aggregate> has no method 'populate'

Comment: @SachinKalsi `from` and `participants` should already be in the results